# MySQL - search date range and group by lowest difference

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, datediff

I need to find one price of all objects that is as near as possible to a desired date range people are searching for. One object can have multiple prices for different date ranges.

Price table

| id | objectid | price | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 50 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | 21 | 60 | 2021-04-02 | 2021-08-01 |
| 3 | 22 | 30 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 4 | 23 | 150 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 5 | 21 | 20 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-09-01 |
| 6 | 23 | 120 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-08-01 |

So lets say people are searching between `2021-05-01` and `2021-06-01` the results should be:

| id | objectid | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 21 | 60 |
| 3 | 22 | 30 |
| 6 | 23 | 120 |

I'm working on this query, but somewhere i lost focus.

```
SELECT p.objectid,
    p.id
    p.start,
    p.end,
    p.price,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(p.start, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(p.end, '2021-06-01')) diff
FROM
    prices AS p1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        p.objectid,
        MIN(
            ABS(
                DATEDIFF(start, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(end, '2021-06-01')
            )
        ) AS diff
    FROM
        prices p
    GROUP BY
        p.objectid
) p2
ON
    p1.objectid = p2.objectid AND diff = p2.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with self join.
Try this below query

```
SELECT
    Y.id,
    Y.objectid,
    Y.price
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        ABS(
            DATEDIFF(`start`, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(`end`, '2021-06-01')
        ) AS `diff`
    FROM
        price
) AS Y
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        *,
        MIN(
            ABS(
                DATEDIFF(`start`, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(`end`, '2021-06-01')
            )
        ) AS diff
    FROM
        price
    GROUP BY
        objectid
) AS X
ON
    X.objectid = Y.objectid AND X.diff = Y.diff
ORDER BY
    Y.id
```

The o/p is this
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you check if the solution i posted is doing the same? Came up yesterday night with it.

Comment: I have not checked your query, you can check your self,
But if your problem is solved then you can close your question by accepting my answer :)

Comment: Sure will do, just wanted to see if you or someone else finds a problem in my solution or a better one.

Comment: The solution you gave it is not running and there is lot of errors. Your solution is not valid.

Comment: Hmm, it runs very well so far.

Comment: Then close your question by accepting my answer and give a up vote :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution that seams to work, but doing a join on the diff could cause blured results i guess.

```
SELECT p.objectid,
    p.id
    p.start,
    p.end,
    p.price
FROM
    prices AS p1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        p.objectid,
        MIN(
            ABS(
                DATEDIFF(start, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(end, '2021-06-01')
            )
        ) AS diff
    FROM
        prices p
    GROUP BY
        p.objectid
) p2
ON
    p1.objectid = p2.objectid AND (ABS(DATEDIFF(p.start, '2021-05-01') + DATEDIFF(p.end, '2021-06-01'))) = p2.diff
```